# First view undesireably renders from second view when an input field event triggered in Backbone app?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have views each with a model and a template and one form model instance to render them from their respective templates. Form model instance is accessible from both view to render their templates. It is needed to update this form model instance on every character typed, and set the model of the current view of the two views with this form model instance. For this I have an `keyup` event on `input` elements in both views, which has different number of input views. Second view has all the same typed, named, id, `input` fields with the first view and some different ones.

When I am on the second view with more input fields and click and type a character in the input field both views have, the first view renders. Calling `this.unbind()` from one of the view before it routes to the other view did not work.

What is the reason for this? I do not have an event to render it when this is done.
mainrouter:

```
    define([
    'jquery',
    'ratchet',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',

    'forms/formsdatamodel',
    'login/loginview',
    'register/registerview',

    'home/homeview',
    ],
    function($, Ratchet, _, Backbone, FormsDataModelInst, LoginView, RegisterView, HomeView){
        var MainRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
            routes: {
                "": "render_home",              
                "login": "render_login",
                "register": "render_register"
            },
            initialize: function(){
                this.model = FormsDataModelInst;
                this.listenTo( this.model, 'change', this.render_home );//this solved render_home problem.
            },
            render_home: function(){
                if( this.model.get('loginp') == true ){ //show you app view for logged in users!
                    this.homeView = new HomeView();
                    this.homeView.render();
                }
                else { //not logged in!
                    Backbone.history.navigate("/login", {trigger:true});
                }
            },
            render_login: function(){ //display your login view
                this.loginView = new LoginView;
                //this.loginView.delegateEvents();
                this.loginView.render();
            },
            render_register: function(){ //display your register view
                this.registerView = new RegisterView;
                //this.registerView.delegateEvents();
                this.registerView.render();
            },
        });

        return MainRouter;
});
```

loginview:

```
    define([
    'jquery',
    'ratchet',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',

    'login/loginmodel',
    'text!login/logintemplate.html',

    'forms/formsdatamodel',

    ],
    function($, Ratchet, _, Backbone, LoginModel, LoginTemplate, FormsDataModelInst){
        var LoginView = Backbone.View.extend({

            el: $('body'),

            initialize: function(){
                this.model = new LoginModel();
            },

            template: _.template( LoginTemplate ),

            render: function(){ //display your login view
                this.$el.html( this.template( FormsDataModelInst.attributes ) );
            },
            events: {
                'keyup input#username' : 'updateModel',
                'click #loginbutton' : 'login',
                'click #renderregisterbutton' : 'render_register',
            },
            updateModel: function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var elm = e.target;
                FormsDataModelInst.set( elm.id, $( elm ).val() );
                this.model.set( FormsDataModelInst );

                console.log( "1-FormsDataModelInst:" + JSON.stringify( FormsDataModelInst.attributes ) );
                console.log( "2-this.model.set(...):" + JSON.stringify(this.model.attributes) );
            },
            login: function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                this.model.save();

                console.log( "3-this.model.save():" + JSON.stringify(this.model.attributes) );
            },
            render_register: function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                this.undelegateEvents();
                Backbone.history.navigate("/register", {trigger:true});
            },
        });

        return LoginView;
});
```

registerview:

```
    define([
    'jquery',
    'ratchet',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',

    'register/registermodel',
    'text!register/registertemplate.html',

    'forms/formsdatamodel',
    ],
    function($, Ratchet, _, Backbone, RegisterModel, RegisterTemplate, FormsDataModelInst){
        var RegisterView = Backbone.View.extend({

            el: $('body'),

            initialize: function(){
                this.model = new RegisterModel();
            },

            template: _.template( RegisterTemplate ),

            render: function(){ //display your login view
                this.$el.html( this.template( FormsDataModelInst.attributes ) );
            },
            events: {
                'keyup input#username' : 'updateModel',
                'keyup input#phone' : 'updateModel',
                'keyup input#email' : 'updateModel',

                'click #registerbutton' : 'register',
                'click #renderloginbutton' : 'render_login',
            },
            updateModel: function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var elm = e.target;
                FormsDataModelInst.set( elm.id, $( elm ).val() );
                this.model.set( FormsDataModelInst );

                console.log( "FormsDataModel:" + JSON.stringify( FormsDataModelInst ) );
                console.log( "this.model.set(...):" + JSON.stringify(this.model.attributes) );
            },
            login: function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                this.model.save();

                console.log( "this.model.save():" + JSON.stringify(this.model) );
            },
            render_login: function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                this.undelegateEvents();
                Backbone.history.navigate("/login", {trigger:true});
            },
        });

        return RegisterView;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mainRouter the listener:

```
this.listenTo( this.formsDataModelInst, 'change', this.render_home );
```

causes the problem of rendering `loginview` undesirebly on typing in `registerview`. Because on `registerview` `keyup` is bound to `updateModels` and this `change`s both `registermodel` and `formsDataModelInst`. this `change` triggers above written event which `route`s to the `loginview` and renders it.

Above listener is needed when `loginp` property of the  `formsDataModelInst` `change`s, to decide which View to render as implemented in `mainRouter` `render`, but not `change`s in the other properties like the ones updated on `keyup` events on form.

Change it to:

```
this.listenTo( this.formsDataModelInst, 'change:loginp', this.render_home );
```

Answer (score 1):

When you instantiate a `View` you setup event bindings on the `el` of that `View`.  It doesn't matter if a different `View` also uses the same `inputs`; as long as the first `View` is still around its event handlers will continue to listen for and respond to events.

You had the right idea by trying to call `this.unbind()` ... except that `View`s don't have an `unbind` method.  They do however have a `undelegateEvents` method, which I think is what you're looking for.

Comment: I've used `this.undelegateEvents()` method in each, loginview and registerview, in a method of each for routing via mainrouter to the other view when a button is clicked in one.

`render_login: function(e){e.preventDefault(); this.undelegateEvents(); Backbone.history.navigate("/login", {trigger:true});},`. through routes of the main router a method called for this render process: `render_login: function(){    this.loginView = new LoginView;
    
    this.loginView.render();
   },`. But still when I start typing in the registerview in any input field immediately loginview comes to the screen.

Comment: Fundamentally what I said remains correct: A) you have an event handler causing the behavior you're seeing, B) that event handler is (presumably) coming from an instance of a Backbone View, C) if you disconnect that handler, ie. by calling `undelegateEvents` on the appropriate `View` it will fix your problem.  Beyond that, I recommend that you edit your question to include the code for your `LoginView` and `RegisterView` classes, as well as your `Router`.  Otherwise it will be difficult, if not impossible, to help you.

Comment: thanks, I have a listenTo that was listening to formsDataModelInst for changes in mainRouter. when on register view I type something updateModels method updated both formsDataModelInst and registerModel. So triggering the method bound to changes on formsDataModel, which is this.render_home method of the mainRouter above. unless loginp is true this method routes back to the login route, so rendering loginview. I have narrowed the change listener on formsDataModelInst to change:loginp. So it works.

Comment: Even that was strangely workin. Even user authenticated and homeview rendered if after sometime one refreshes the page and again loginview. Then rerefreshes again homeview. Later I had wrote listenTo s only listens to sync event nad trigger a navigate instead of creating and rendering.